# nested IF(AND(ISBLANK)) Statement not working?

Tags: excel

I have a formula that is supposed to place an "X" if a value populated in one or more of three columns (J,R,AL).

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(J:J),ISBLANK(R:R)),ISBLANK(AL:AL))),"","x")
```

It gives an argument error message, and I know it has something to do with the syntax structure of the parentheses. Can anyone help me figure out how to edit this?

Comment: Why are you looking at whole columns? I would expect you to be looking at a specific row like `=IF(AND(ISBLANK(J1),ISBLANK(R1),ISBLANK(AL1)),"","x")`

Comment: Alternate: `=IF(J1&R1&AL1="","","x")`

Comment: @tigeravatar I've entered in this: =if(and(isblank(J2),isblank(R2)),isblank(AL2))),"","x") and it's saying I still have too many arguments

Comment: See Ian MacDonald's answer for an explanation of the too many arguments.  I did correct the formula in my comment, as well as offered an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier variation of your formula would be

```
=IF(COUNTA(J:J, R:R, AL:AL) > 0, "X", "")
```

---

Formula `COUNTA` counts non-empty cells. So the moment there is one non-empty it means there is data somewhere in at least one of these columns.

In my opinion, a much more elegant solution

---

**EDIT:** As found out in the comments, formula isn't supposed to check for entire column, but only for values in the colums per row. So, it should be:

(presuming your data starts at `J1`, `R1`, `AL1`)

```
=IF(COUNTA(J1, R1, A1) > 0, "X", "")
```

This will return the desired result

Comment: @bloomfieldhero9219 can't be. I've tested it and it works. Try literally copy-pasting it

Comment: It's populating an X in every row, not just the rows with values

Comment: @bloomfieldhero9219 in your question, you said and I'm citing: "*If a value is populated in one or more of three of the columns J, R, AL*", this implies the entire column!! Hence I made the formula that way. But oh well... let me edit the answer. I'd like to stress importance of a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here and how it could have prevented this misunderstanding

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is place an "X" if there is a value in one or more of the columns by each row. So Column J and R could contain values, Columns J and AL could have them, all three could, or just one individually. This needs to go by every row individually to see if one or more values are populated in those three columns

Comment: No problem, just wanted to make sure the solution worked  :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me exactly what you have intended here, but you have an inappropriate number of parentheses. Google Sheets detects this error correctly right away, and I would be surprised if Excel didn't also give you a clearer error message.

```
=IF(
  AND(
    ISBLANK(J:J),ISBLANK(R:R)
     ),
  ISBLANK(AL:AL)
   )
),"","x")   /// <--- all of this is trailing junk
```

Perhaps your intention was to check if all of them were blank? You would still have one too many parentheses and you would need an extra `AND`, but at least your number of arguments would also make more sense.

```
=IF(AND(AND(ISBLANK(J:J),ISBLANK(R:R)),ISBLANK(AL:AL)),"","x")
```